# Why is this definition returning False instead of True?

Tags: python-3.7

I'm not understanding why it only checks the first number of the list. (Number 4 in has23([4, 3]) and it breaks. Why doesn't it go back up and check for number 3? I need this definition to return True.

I've been trying to separate it with an 'elif' in between but no luck.

```
def has23(nums):
  for num in nums:
    if num == 2 or num == 3:
      return True

    else:
      return False

has23([4, 3])
```

No error message. It returns false instead of True.

Comment: Because of `else` statement

Comment: well that depends on your input (`nums`). For example if your input was  `[3,4]` it would return True. Also you do realize that your for loop will exit upon the first element in nums, right? You are using returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the return statement, it will break the for loop and return false if the first value in the array doesn't match the condition.

The code should be something like this (I'm not a python coder)

```
def has23(nums):
  for num in nums:
    if num == 2 or num == 3:
      return True
  return False  # This return statement should be after the for loop
has23([4, 3])
```

Comment: Don't need to iterate through list

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because whenever `if` or `else` condition is satisfied `return` is taking it out of `def`. So it is better to store the result in a list and `return` the list. 

`status=[]
def has23(nums):
  for num in nums:
        if num == 2 or num == 3: status.append(True);
        else: status.append(False)
  return status
print has23([4,3])`

Answer (score 0):

```
def has23(nums):
    if 2 in nums or 2 in nums:
        return True
    else:
        return False

has23([4, 2])
```

Hope this will work